# Can you advise on how to structure the problem proposed?

Tags: java, design-patterns, object-oriented-analysis

I'm re-working an old procedural algorithm in object oriented programming, and I'm trying to design the different classes/objects.

The algorithm is executing a couple of functions/methods.
The output of each method will be used as an input the following one.
Based on some initial condition, some functions can be skipped.

So let's say we have the following use cases:

| FIRST | SECOND | THIRD | FOURTH |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| initializeVariables() | initializeVariables() | initializeVariables() | initializeVariables() |  |
| saveTemporaryData() | saveTemporaryData() | saveTemporaryData() | saveTemporaryData() |  |
| addDataFromExternalSource() | addDataFromDraft() | addDataFromDraft() | addDataFromPreviousVersion() |  |
| sortData() | addDataFromExternalSource() | addDataFromPreviousVersion() | addDataFromExternalSource() |  |
| prepareOutput() | sortData() | addDataFromExternalSource() | sortData() |  |
|  | prepareOutput() | sortData() | prepareOutput() |  |
|  |  | prepareOutput() |  |  |

I started thinking to create an abstract class that contains the implementation of the methods that are common to all the use cases, and let subclasses implement the methods not in the abstract class.
And then have an "execute" method in each implementation that calls the different methods one by one based on the use case.
But I'm not satisfied of this approach, there's still repetition.

Do you have any suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: why -1? Is this not a valid question for this website? Or I didn't phrase it correctly - missing something? Thanks!

Comment: I think the -1 was left because the question is too broad. Without knowing what the methods do, it's hard to answer your question. Maybe try to be more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this doesn’t show any intentional effort and feels a bit like you’re asking us to do homework for you. That being said, with the example given you can just use a null check to determine if optional methods should be called, such as:

```
public class Example {
    Draft draft;
    void saveTemporaryData() {
        //TODO logic
        if(draft != null) addDataFromDraft();
        addDataFromExternalSources();
    }

    void addDataFromDraft() {
        //TODO logic
    }

    void addDataFromExternalSources() {
        //TODO logic
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the proposal, I was thinking at a way to avoid IF condtions. 
As for the "intentional effort" I explained in the second part of the question my first approach and why I don't like it. So I've done an effort, I can always add more detail to it with some code. Thanks anyway for your proposal !

Comment: No worries. I can't currently think of any way to avoid lots of repetition without using conditionals, but best of luck!

Comment: I also can't think of easy ways to avoid IFs without complexifying too much. I'd just change addDataFromDraft() to getDataFromDraft and put it on a separate Draft class. Thanks again for your help!